# DataGridViewComboBoxCell edit field

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` connected to a list of strings:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
List<string> data = new List<string>() { "88","LinearCurve", "NonLinearCurve" };
cell.DataSource = data;
cell.ReadOnly = false;
cell.Value = data[0];
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] = cell;
```

But is it possible to edit these fields on runtime when I double click the cell?

When "88" is chosen, I should be able to doubleclick and change the text to "89". The string list data should now contain "89", "LinearCurve" and "NonLinearCurve".

The point with this is that input is either a number free of choice or a predefined string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to edit the values in your `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`, we will handle the following events:

```
this.dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;
this.dataGridView1.CellValidating += DataGridView1_CellValidating;
this.dataGridView1.DataError += DataGridView1_DataError;
```

Also, in order to perpetuate the value change to the `cell.Value`, we'll change your setup to this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
cell.Items.AddRange("88", "LinearCurve", "NonLinearCurve");
cell.Value = cell.Items[0];
cell.ReadOnly = false;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] = cell;
```

Handling `EditingControlShowing` our purpose is to change the `ComboBox.DropDownStyle` to `DropDown` (editable) when the first item (the editable number) is selected and to `DropDownList` (not editable) otherwise:

```
private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell == this.dataGridView1[0,0])
    {
        ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;

        if (cb != null)
        {
            cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= Cb_SelectedIndexChanged;

            // Following line needed for initial setup.
            cb.DropDownStyle = cb.SelectedIndex == 0 ? ComboBoxStyle.DropDown : ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

            cb.SelectedIndexChanged += Cb_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
    }
}

private void Cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    cb.DropDownStyle = cb.SelectedIndex == 0 ? ComboBoxStyle.DropDown : ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
}
```

Handling `CellValidating` our purpose is to change the value of the first item to the user entered value, if that value is not empty and isn't already in the list. We also need to commit the edit changes and set the `cell.Value`:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == 0)
    {
        var cell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;

        if (cell != null && e.FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty && !cell.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue))
        {
            cell.Items[0] = e.FormattedValue;

            if (this.dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }

            cell.Value = e.FormattedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, handling `DataError` our purpose is to catch an error that gets thrown when the new value is set in the `ComboBox.Items`. The cell will complain trying to set that new value, but it still works - so the error can be ignored:

```
private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == 0)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Side note:

If you have one of your non-editable values selected and start typing on the cell, it will attempt to select a matching value.  For example, if the first item in the list is "88" and you already have "LinearCurve" selected, typing "8" will auto select "88" - which for the first item will force editable mode. So it will *appear* as though you've started editing a non-editable value, but you're not. It's just a quirk of the `ComboBox`.

Answer (score -1):

If you set the cell's ReadOnly property to false, it would leave you edit the content of that cell.

Try this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
cell.ReadOnly = false;
```

Comment: I did not work. I have changed my text a little in order to better explain what to do. Maybe I have to change the cell type at runtime in order to change the text?

Answer (score -1):

set value member and display member for comboboxcell